# Getting error while deploying in tomcat 5.5

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I was trying to deploy an application on tomcat 5.5 I am getting the below error , I have spring 2.5.6 jar in my classpath , Please advise..

```
EVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1438)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Oct 1, 2012 1:33:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
```

Please advise as I am stuck up because of this..!!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the spring-web.jar library, or it's not in the proper location for tomcat to see it. The libraries should go under /WEB-INF/lib/ in your webapp or in a global lib directory. See: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html all the locations from where tomcat is loading libraries.

Comment: Please advise in detail as I have done this also by explicitly keepeing spring -web.jar in lib folder

Comment: Is your spring-web.jar in WEB-INF/lib/ of your webapp war? It's not clear what do you mean with 'in lib folder'. Like I said, the jar should be in one of the locations that Tomcat understands.

Comment: I have added the required jars through configure build path project option in eclipse and finally it all the required jars are listed in web application jars folder